# How to integrate$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx$ without power series expansion

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I happen to watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVCv8RrQOSs&list=WL&index=78&t=808s),
which gives a solution to the definite integral below using the power series approach. Then answer is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, given by:

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}du=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$$

where the power seires expansion of the function $\ln(1+u)$ is used.

I tried for some time, but could not find another approach. Does anyone know any alternative methods to evaluate above definite integral without using the infinite series expansion?

Any comments, or ideas, are really appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884418/how-to-evaluate-int-01-int-01-frac11-xy-dy-dx-to-prove-sum-n) might answer your question.

Comment: @r9m, Thank you very much!

Comment: Your integral is a special case of $~\displaystyle\frac{1}{n!}\int\frac{(\ln(x+z))^n}{x-a}\,dx =\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(\ln(x+z))^k}{k!}(-1)^{n-k+1}\text{Li}_{n-k+1}\left(\frac{x+z}{a+z}\right) + C~$ ; $~(n,a,z):=(1,1,0)~$ .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is to integrate without resorting to power series. Note
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx& =\frac43\int_0^1  \frac{\ln x }{1-x}dx -\frac13\int_0^1 { \frac{\ln x }{1-x} } \overset{x\to x^2}{dx} \\
&= \frac43\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx
= \frac23\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx=\frac23J(1)
\end{align}

where $ J(\alpha) =-\frac 12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1-\alpha^2 + \alpha^2 x^2)}{x^2-1}dx $

$$ J'(\alpha) =-\int_0^\infty \frac{\alpha dx}{1-\alpha^2 + \alpha^2 x^2}  = -\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}$$

Thus

$$ \int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx = \frac23\int_0^1 J'(\alpha) d\alpha =-\frac{\pi}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{d\alpha}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}= -\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: Where does this function $J$ come from? It doesn't look like one could guess that just from the computation up that point.

Comment: @quarague - $I = \int_0^1 J'(a)da$ is a known technique in definite integration to 'bypass' the original integral which is usually hard to do directly. The actual form of $J(a)$ depends on the integrand of $I$; it requires some search or guess, though.

Comment: @Quanto, thanks very much for this nice answer!

Comment: I'm having a tough time following the early steps. Where did $t$ come from and how is it defined?

Comment: @Polygon - there was a typo, which is fixed now

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro

Comment: @Quanto "$I = \int_0^1 \,J'(a)da$ is a known technique...".  **Really?** 
My calculus experience is limited to Volume 1 of "Calculus 2nd Edition"
by Apostol.

It probably doesn't surprise you that I didn't know about this technique.
Can you suggest Calculus/Real-Analysis books (or pdf's) devoted to an organized
presentation of various techniques for definite &/or indefinite integration?

Comment: @user2661923 [The technique in question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) is often referred to as Feynman's trick, so googling that may help you find the most impressive examples of this inventive but often thorny technique.

Comment: @J.G. nice response, thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 - check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453227/when-to-differentiate-under-the-integral-sign/3453393#3453393

Comment: Nice solution.  I've posted a complementary solution that you might enjoy.  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way of showing that $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx=\pi^2/6$.  First, enforce the substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$ to obtain

$$I=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx$$

Then, noting that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dy=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$ we write $I$ as

$$I=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy\tag1$$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884418/how-to-evaluate-int-01-int-01-frac11-xy-dy-dx-to-prove-sum-n), I used the transformation $x=s+t$, $y=s-t$ to write the double integral in $(1)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_{-s}^{s}\frac{2}{(1-s^2)+t^2}\,dt\,ds+\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_{s-1}^{1-s}\frac{2}{(1-s^2)+t^2}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\right)\,ds\\\\&+\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-s}{1+s}}\right)\,ds\\\\
&=4\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\arcsin(s)}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\,ds+4\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\arccos(s)}{2\sqrt{1-s^2}}\,ds\\\\
&=2\arcsin^2(1/2)+\arccos^2(1/2)\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^2\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: thank you very much for this nice answer! I have already voted this answer. Because Quanto's answer was posed earlier, so I accept that one. Wish you stay strong and safe too !

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased to see that this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

- [Using diagamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)

$$\begin{align*}
& \color{blue}{I = \int_0^1 \frac {\ln x}{x-1}dx}\\
\end{align*}$$

Now,
$$\color{red}{\psi_0 (z) = -\gamma + \int_0^{1} \frac {x^{z-1}-1}{x-1}dx}$$
We'll differentiate and that is [trigamma function $\psi_1(z)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html)

$$\implies \frac {\partial\psi_0}{\partial z}= \psi_1 (z) = \int_0^1 \frac {x^{z-1}\ln x}{x-1}dx$$
$$\color{green}{I = \left[\psi_1(z)\right]_{z=1} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}}$$

[I have copied this answer from my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4294747/in-an-attempt-to-find-i-int-0-infty-fractet-1dt/4294782#4294782)