# Evaluate integral $ \int _0 ^ \infty \frac {dx} {x^3 (e^\frac{\pi}{x} -1)}$ without Taylor expansion

Tags: integration, analysis

How to compute the integral below:
$$ \int _0 ^ \infty \frac {dx} {x^3 (e^\frac{\pi}{x} -1)}$$
I have trouble in dealing with the item of $e^ \frac{\pi} {x} -1$ without the method of Taylor expansion.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Did you try $u=\pi/x$?

Comment: I do try that, but the item of $e^x-1$ is also the trouble.

Comment: @yufenglu are you allowed to use techniques from multivariable calculus (multiple integrals and a change of variables, specifically) in your solution?

Comment: Maybe not I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reexpress the integral with the substitution $y=e^{-\frac\pi x}$

$$ \int _0 ^ \infty \frac {dx} {x^3 (e^\frac{\pi}{x} -1)}
=\frac1{\pi^2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y }{y-1}dy$$
Then, evaluate [$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y }{y-1}dy = \frac{\pi^2}6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403819/how-to-integrate-int-01-frac-ln-xx-1dx-without-power-series-expansion/3404200#3404200) without Tayler expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $t=\frac {\pi}x$
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^3(e^{\pi/x}-1)}=\frac 1{\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t}-1}\,dt.
$$
Use integral representation of riemann zeta function
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac 1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1}\,dt.
$$
Put $s=2$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac 1{\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t}-1}\,dt&=\frac 1{\pi^2}\zeta(2)\\
&=\frac 16
\end{align}