# $\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=I$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=I$$
I tried to do it as usual but I am finding it hard to do. I have calculated the first integral as this but struck after that.

$$-\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
Please help.

Comment: This is a very famous problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3404200/686284

Answer (score 1):

Seems you went the correct way, expanding the log into Taylor series, and got the correct expression just typed wrong index. Yours is a famous series,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$