# $\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$ without using series

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How to compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$? I know how to do this by using series, but I'm interested in other solutions. For example, is this possible to do with complex analysis? If it is, what is contour of integration?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zeta function $Integral\ Representation$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=e^{-t}$ to rewrite the integral as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx
$$
Then, refer to the non-series solution of [$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3404200/686284)

Comment: Or use [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403819/how-to-integrate-int-01-frac-ln-xx-1dx-without-power-series-expansion/4041079#4041079) solution which avoids series expansion.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very special integral.
Let,
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
Substitute $t=nu\implies dt=ndu$
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)}{n^{s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{s-1}e^{-nu}du$$
Run sum on both sides with $n$ from $0$ to $\infty$.
$$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{u}-1}du$$
Setting $s=2$ we have that,
$$\Gamma(2)\zeta(2)=\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$$
Which is $\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$

Comment: That uses series.

Comment: Oo, I didn't notice the question properly, my mistake.

Comment: There is no series written for this question

Answer (score 2):

One way in terms of the dilogarithm function:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}t}{1-e^{-t}}dt= \int_1^0 \frac{\ln(w)}{1-w}dw = \int_1^0 \frac{\ln(1-r)}{r}dr= \operatorname{Li}_{2}(1)= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another method, which applies in quite a few other situations, is to use the *Hankel* or *keyhole* contour: a path coming in from $+\infty$ "just below" the real axis, traversing a small circle clockwise, and going out to $+\infty$ "just above" the positive real axis. The details are documented in many places. This method gives a way to evaluate $\zeta(s)$ for $s$ non-positive integer, and appeared in B. Riemann's 1858 paper on $\zeta$.

Answer (score 1):

- [What is Diagamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)

$$\begin{align*}
& \color{blue}{I = \int_0^1 \frac {\ln x}{x-1}dx}\\
\end{align*}$$

Now,
$$\color{red}{\psi_0 (z) = -\gamma + \int_0^{1} \frac {x^{z-1}-1}{x-1}dx}$$
We'll differentiate and that is [Trigamma function $\psi_1(z)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html)

$$\implies \frac {\partial\psi_0}{\partial z}= \psi_1 (z) = \int_0^1 \frac {x^{z-1}\ln x}{x-1}dx$$
$$\color{green}{I = \left[\psi_1(z)\right]_{z=1} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}}$$

[Copied from thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4294747/in-an-attempt-to-find-i-int-0-infty-fractet-1dt/4294782#4294782)