# Complex integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{z-1}\,\mathrm dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How do we evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{z-1}\,\mathrm dz\,?$$
Here contour of integration consists of
\begin{align*}
\gamma_R(t)&=1+R\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}\quad&\text{for}\quad&t\in[0,\pi],\\
l_1(t)&=t&\text{for}\quad&t\in[1-R,1-\epsilon],\\
\gamma_\epsilon(t)&=1+\epsilon\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it}&\text{for}\quad&t\in[-\pi,0]\\
\text{and}\quad l_2(t)&=t&\text{for}\quad&t\in[1+\epsilon,1+R].
\end{align*}
Am I right so far? How should I approach the rest of the calculation Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Substitute $z=e^t$ and transform to a zeta function integral.

Comment: This is a very well known integral with multiple solution methods, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403819/how-to-integrate-int-01-frac-ln-xx-1dx-without-power-series-expansion) for instance.