# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x\cdot \tanh^{-1}(x)}{3+x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to evaluate the integral

$$ I = \int_0^1 \frac{x \tanh^{-1}x}{3+x^2} dx$$

To solve this, I considered the family of integrals

$$ I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{ x \tanh^{-1}ax}{3+x^2} dx$$

Note that $I(0) = 0$.

Using Leibnitz rule, we get:

$$ I'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{(x^2+3)-(3)}{(3+x^2)(1-a^2x^2)}dx$$

$$I'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1-a^2x^2} + 3\cdot \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x^2+3)(a^2x^2-1)}$$

Multiplying and dividing by $a^2$ for the second integral, we get:

$$I'(a) = \frac{1}{2a} \cdot \ln(\frac{1+a}{1-a}) + 3\cdot a \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{adx}{(a^2x^2+3a^2)(a^2x^2-1)}$$

For the second integral, I substitute $ax = v$

$$I_0(a) = 3a\cdot \int_0^a \frac{dv}{(v^2+3a^2)(v^2-1)}$$

$$ = \frac{3a}{3a^2+1} \cdot (\int_0^a \frac{dv}{v^2-1} - \int_0^a \frac{dv}{v^2+3a^2})$$

$$I_0(a) = \frac{3a}{3a^2+1} \cdot ( \frac{1}{2}\cdot \ln(\frac{1-a}{1+a}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt3 a}\cdot \frac{\pi}{6})$$

Adding the integrals, we get:

$$I'(a) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac{1}{a} - \frac{3a}{3a^2+1}) \ln(\frac{1+a}{1-a}) - \frac{\sqrt3}{3a^2+1} \cdot \frac{\pi}{6} $$

This means that

$$ I(b) = \int_0^b I'(a) da$$

But I'm not sure how to integrate the first part of $I'(a)$ - that is, I am struggling to evaluate:

$$I_1(b) = \int_0^b \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac{1}{a}-\frac{3a}{3a^2+1}) \ln(\frac{1+a}{1-a}) da$$

$$I_1(b) = \int_0^b \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{a(3a^2+1)} \ln(\frac{1+a}{1-a}) da$$

We proceed by substituting $\frac{1-a}{1+a} = t$ in the integrand and obtain:

$$I_1(b) = -\frac{1}{4}\cdot \int_{\frac{1-b}{1+b}}^1 \frac{\operatorname{ln}t\cdot (1+t)}{(t^2-t+1)\cdot (1-t)}dt$$

Can anyone help me in evaluating this specific integral? I would like to know the strategies used to evaluate integrals of such kinds.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: $\frac{\pi^2}{72}$

Comment: @MathAttack Yes, that's correct for $b=1$. But I am interested in a general expression, if possible.

Comment: Ah ok... give me some minutes

Comment: What gave you the idea to substitute $\frac{1-a}{1+a}=t$?

Comment: @Zacky It was the weirdest looking part in the integral.

Comment: I totally agree. However this is also the weirdest part in the original integral.. so it would only be natural to use it directly there (which should solve the integral after  partial fractions and IBP).

Comment: The method I would try: set $x=\tanh t$, $dx = (1-\tanh^2)dt$ to get an integral from $0$ to $\infty$, use parity to get an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, apply residues formula to the function $f : z \mapsto z^2\tanh z(1-\tanh^2z)/(3+\tanh^2z)$ on the boundary of the rectangle with vertices $\pm R$ and $\pm R+i\pi$, use the identity $\tanh(z+i\pi) = \tanh z$ and let $R$ go to infinity.

Comment: $I_1(b)$ computed

Comment: Which method are you asking about ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry I had not seen your edit. Thanks for the revised answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, reduce the integral to the familiar [$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}x dx= \frac{\pi^2}6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3404200/686284) as follows

\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x \tanh ^{-1}x}{x^2+3}\overset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{dx} 
=& \ \frac14 \int_0^1\ln x\ d \left( \ln\frac{(1+x)^2}{x^2+x+1}\right)\\
\overset{ibp}= & \ \frac14 \int_0^1\frac1x \ln\frac{(1-x^2)^2}{(1-x)(1-x^3)}\ dx\\
=& \ \frac1{12} \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}x dx=\frac{\pi^2}{72}
\end{align}
where $\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx
= 2\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx 
= 3\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1-x^3)}{x}dx $ is used in the simplification.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution, Quanto!

Answer (score 2):

$$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x \tanh ^{-1}(a x)}{x^2+3}\,dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+3\right) \left(1-a^2 x^2\right)}\,dx$$ $$I'(a)=\frac{1}{3 a^2+1}\int_0^1 \Bigg(\frac{1}{1-a^2 x^2}-\frac{3}{x^2+3} \Bigg)\,dx$$
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{2(3 a^2+1)}\Bigg(\frac 1a \log \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)-\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}  \Bigg)$$
$$I(a)=-\frac{\pi ^2}{18}+\frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac 1 {a(3a^2+1)} \log \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)\,da$$
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac 1 {a(3a^2+1)} \log \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)\,da$$ $$J=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{3 a}{3 a^2+1}\right)\log \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)\,da$$
$$J=\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2}{9}=\frac{5\pi ^2}{36}$$ Recombining everything
$$I(1)=-\frac{\pi ^2}{18}+\frac{5\pi ^2}{72}=\frac{\pi ^2}{72}$$

Comment: Thank you for your swift response as always, Claude Leibovici! Can you elucidate on how did you obtain the final expression for $J$? Also - as I have asked in the question - can we obtain a closed form for $I(a)$?

Answer (score 2):

I'll write you the final result (the process is quite long if you're interested I can write you the basic steps in the comments)

For $a\in(0,1)$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\cdot\operatorname{tanh^{-1}}(ax)}{x^2+3}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)+\operatorname{cot^{-1}}\left(\sqrt{3}a\right)^{2}-K(a)}{2}+\operatorname{tanh^{-1}}\left(a\right)\ln\left(\frac{2a}{\sqrt{3a^{2}+1}}\right)$$

Where:

- $\text{Li}_2(x)$ is the polylogarithm function
- $\displaystyle K(a):=\Re\left[\text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{(a-1)(\sqrt{3}a-i)}{(a+1)(\sqrt{3}a+i)}\right)\right]$

You can easily compute $K(a)$ through the polylogarithm series:
$$\text{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k^2}\qquad |z|\leq1$$
For $a\in[0,1]$
$$K(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(2k\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\sqrt{3}a\right)\right)}{k^{2}}\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)^{k}$$

I'll leave you the [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s2qfkqrwx4?lang=it) where I wrote the final result.

Comment: Please do write the steps. I am completely new to polylogarithms.

Answer (score 2):

$$I_1(b) = -\frac{1}{4}\, \int_{\frac{1-b}{1+b}}^1 \frac{(1+t)\,\log(t)}{(t^2-t+1)\,(1-t)}dt$$

Let
$$t^2-t+1=(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)\qquad \text{where} \qquad(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1\pm i \sqrt{3}}{2} $$
Use partial fraction decomposition
$$I_1(b)=\int_{\frac{1-b}{1+b}}^1 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{2 (t-1)}-\frac{\log (t)}{4 (t-\alpha )}-\frac{\log (t)}{4 (t-\beta
   )}\right)\,dt$$ to face three integrals
$$J(\gamma)=\int_c^1 \frac{\log (t)}{t-\gamma }\,dt$$
$$J(\gamma)=-\log (c) \log \left(1-\frac{c}{\gamma
   }\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{c}{\gamma
   }\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\gamma }\right)$$

As a total, with $c=\frac{1-b}{1+b}$
$$I_1(b) =-\frac{\pi ^2}{72}+\frac{1}{4} \log (c) \log \left(c^2-c+1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(1-c)+$$
$$\frac 14\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2} 
   c\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-i
   \sqrt{3}}{2} c\right)\right)$$

Expanded as a series around $b=1$
$$I_1(b) =\frac{5\pi ^2}{72}+\frac 18\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\, P_n \, (b-1)^n$$ where $P_n$ write
$$P_n=\gamma_n\, L+\delta_n \qquad \text{with} \qquad L=\log \left(\frac{2}{1-b}\right)$$

The first of them are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n \\
 1 & L+1 \\
 2 & \frac{5}{4}L+\frac{3}{8} \\
 3 & \frac{4 }{3}L-\frac{1}{72} \\
 4 & \frac{41 }{32}L-\frac{103}{384} \\
 5 & \frac{91 }{80}L-\frac{1963}{4800} \\
 6 & \frac{91 }{96}L-\frac{1759}{3840} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry! I missed another $\frac{1}{a}$ term in the integrand.